# Subquery to see if a field in a separate table is null or empty for the same id

Tags: php, mysql, sql, wordpress

I am getting authors this way:

```
$feat_authors = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT ID, user_nicename from $wpdb->users WHERE display_name <> 'admin' ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 3");
```

But I want to check in a seperate database table: `wp_usermeta` where there is a field `meta_key='description'` to see if its *value* **is not empty or null** for the associated ID (user_id and ID from the first table match).

Selecting and printing `wp_usermeta` yields:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [umeta_id] => 19
            [user_id] => 2
            [meta_key] => first_name
            [meta_value] => Rita
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [umeta_id] => 20
            [user_id] => 2
            [meta_key] => last_name
            [meta_value] => Santos
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [umeta_id] => 21
            [user_id] => 2
            [meta_key] => nickname
            [meta_value] => rita
        )

    [3] => stdClass Object
        (
            [umeta_id] => 22
            [user_id] => 2
            [meta_key] => description
            [meta_value] => I’m the coolest person in Uniplaces. I also post stuff on Facebook and other social networks.
        )
```

And I tried this, which I know gives me all the empty descriptions: `SELECT * FROM wp_usermeta WHERE meta_key = 'description' AND meta_value = ''`

But I'm not sure how to combine them so that in the first query I only get results where the description in the second table is not empty or null. Another thing that is throwing me off is that I'm not sure how to bring the id over to the second query as the first id has a different named (ID as opposed to user_id).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not 100% sure I am getting what you are asking for, but can you use a join to that table with extra data and a case statement?

```
SELECT 
    ID
    , user_nicename 
    ,CASE 
        WHEN Len([meta_key='description'])>0 THEN 'Some Content'
        WHEN Len([meta_key='description'])=0 THEN 'No Content'
        WHEN [meta_key='description'] Is Null THEN 'Null'
        ELSE 'OTHER'
     END AS Category
from $wpdb->users as u
    left outer join wp_usermeta as m
        ON u.ID=m.user_id
WHERE display_name <> 'admin' 
ORDER BY rand() 
LIMIT 3
```

If you only want to see users who DONT have null or empty descriptions maybe:

```
SELECT 
    ID
    , user_nicename 
    ,[meta_key='description']
from $wpdb->users as u
    INNER JOIN wp_usermeta as m
        ON u.ID=m.user_id
WHERE 
    display_name <> 'admin' 
    AND Len([meta_key='description'])>0
    AND [meta_key='description'] IS NOT NULL -- probably not required depending on len() behaviour
ORDER BY rand() 
LIMIT 3
```

OR maybe you have multiple records in your second table per user and you want where meta_key = description?

```
SELECT 
    ID
    , user_nicename 
    ,meta_value
from $wpdb->users as u
    left outer join wp_usermeta as m
        ON u.ID=m.user_id
        AND meta_key='description'
WHERE 
    display_name <> 'admin' 
    AND Len(meta_value)>0
ORDER BY rand() 
LIMIT 3
```

I just had a quick look at the table structures and i think you want somthing like option 3

Comment: Thanks for the effort but I just want to exclude the rows in the $wpdb->users that do not have an associated value for the description. Not typify the results like you are doing in the case. So the exact opposite of the second solution you posted because I just want the ones with descriptions. Which I suppose just means I have to change IS NULL to IS NOT NULL and =0  to <> '' ?

Comment: Yes something like that should work also remove the `len(` part.

Comment: use an inner join instead of a left join given the above alex.  And then you can ignore the whole is null and case statements.  I get where gordatron was going given how you asked the question.  But this just seems like a simple "inner join"  for more on Joins review this excellent article: http://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/.  Inner Join: Only return records which exist in both tables based on key value.

Comment: Agreed.. if it is as i think it is then an inner join is fine. just not 100% sure what you data looks like.. updating answer

Comment: i keep getting getting a blank array which is strange because I can't seem to find any errors in your code (working off the middle example btw). Perhaps take a look at the tables? https://codex.wordpress.org/Database_Description#Table:_wp_usermeta and https://codex.wordpress.org/Database_Description#Table:_wp_users

Comment: wait got it! thanks a bunch ;) for future reference: SELECT ID, user_nicename, meta_key='description', meta_value FROM $wpdb->users as u INNER JOIN wp_usermeta as m ON u.ID=m.user_id WHERE display_name <> 'admin' AND meta_key='description' AND meta_value <> '' ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 3

Comment: I just hada  quick look at teh table structure i think that something like the third example is what you are looking for.. again an INNER JOIN Is fine